# Django Rest Framework Model Serializer Custom Field

Tags: django, angularjs, django-rest-framework, angular-resource

I'm using Django Rest Framework and AngularJS.
I have **Task** and **Client** models. The **Client** model is a Foreign Key for **Task**.

mInside *serializers.py*, the **ClientSerializer()** looks like:

```
class ClientBasicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'gender')
```

And the **TaskSerializer()** (not working) looks like this:

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    client = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    client_data = serializers.ClientSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Task
```

As can be seen:

- **client** retrieves only the PK. I'm using it to save the Task model with AngularJS resource.
- **client_data** contains the nested client object. I need it to display the client information for the user.

However, it does not work because there is no client_data field defined inside the Django Client Model (and I think I shouldn't define it).

How can I define it as a custom field inside the **TaskSerializer()** and still take advantage of the **ClientSerializer()**?

Answer (score 0):

You can use just `client = serializers.ClientSerializer()`

Then, you need to rewrite your `create` method in order to assign client instance to the created task instance.

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    client = serializers.ClientSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Task

    def create(self, validated_data):

        client_id = validated_data['client'] # this should be client id
        client = Client.objects.get(id=client_id)
        del(validated_data['client'])
        task = Task.objects.create(**validated_data)
        task.client = client
        task.save()
        return save.
```

Comment: I think my problem is the opposite. The TaskSerializer is retrieving the full Client model to the view, but I only need to pass the client_id when I update a certain task, and not the full Client dictionary. How can I change the code above to reflect this issue?

Comment: @BrunnoVodolaMartins read my code, you don't need to pass full `Client` dictionary, just pass `client id` as `client` attribute. In `validated_data['client']` should has `client id`